# Seg Fault Looping over C++ containers

Tags: c++, std

Here's the code(find union of 2 sets) :

```
template <class dtype>
void printSet(dtype data)
{
    std::cout<<"\n";
    for(auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<*i<<" ,";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::set<long long> a(arr, arr + 5), b(arr, arr + 5), c;
    std::vector<long long> v;
    b.insert(1000);
    printSet(a);
    printSet(b);
    set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), v.begin());
    printSet(v);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's what I got:

```
1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,
[1]    9444 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

Where did I mess up ?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? Did you try turning on debug mode checking in your standard library implementation? (e.g. `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for G++.)   If not, that's where you messed up.

Comment: Thanx. I'll try to enable debug mode for clang.

Comment: If you're using clang with libstdc++ then it's also `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, if you're using clang with libc++ then _I think_ it's `-D_LIBCPP_DEBUG2`

Comment: Is it different from '-g' option for clang++?

Comment: Yes. That includes debugging symbols in the executable, it doesn't alter the code that is generated and doesn't enable your standard library's error-checking "debug mode". You need `-g` to be able to use a debugger on the program, but that's not the same as turning on the library's "debug mode"

Comment: Could have removed `printSet` entirely from this testcase.

Comment: I had thought thats where the problem is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`v` is empty, so writing to `v.begin()` isn't possible. You should use `std::back_inserter(v)` instead.

Answer (score 6):

`set_union` expects a valid output iterator, in the sense that it should be allowed to write at that iterator. `v` is empty, so `v.begin()` isn't a valid iterator.

Try declaring your vector as

```
std::vector<long long> v(42);
```

Comment: Given the wording of the OP's question, it may be worth emphasizing that the segfault is not, in fact, during looping over the container, even though the output makes it seem as such. This is why you should clear the output buffer often.

Comment: This will work as long as the union results in less than 42 objects (which obviously is the case in this example), however in general it would be preferred (in my opinion, at least) to use `std::back_inserter`, as suggested below.

Comment: @suszterpatt Ah.. forgot about the buffers. thanx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity: if you flush `std::cout` before the `set_union` line, you should see that `b` was printed as well.

As to the error, I suggest adding this include:

```
#include <iterator>
```

and changing your `set_union` line to:

```
set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), back_inserter(v));
```

The `back_insert_iterator` returned by `back_inserter` is an output iterator suitable for use here: it will call `v.push_back` for each item assigned to it by `set_union`.

---

### A note on your platform & environment:

In general, you should make sure your core file size limit is non-zero (just make it unlimited unless you're writing massive programs), and learn to examine the core file with your debugger.